# Binary file to python integer list

Tags: python, c, arrays, python-2.7, io

I have a list of 1,000,000 ints stored as a binary file. How do I load this quickly into a Python list? In C I would just read the file into a char array and cast that array as an int array. Is there a way to do something equivalent to this in Python? I know about Python's struct module, but as far as I can tell, that would require an extremely long format string to convert all the ints at once.

Comment: `struct.unpack('1000000I',f.read())` doesn't seem too long to me.

Comment: if you don't like struct, use `r=array.array('i');r.fromfile(...)`.

Comment: Thank you @roippi. I wasn't aware you could specify repetition in the format string. Should have read the documentation more carefully :)

Answer (score 0):

`struct.unpack('1000000I',f.read())` doesn't seem too long to me. –  roippi